# Windows 8.1 Partition not visible in ubuntu 14.04 installation

Tags: 14.04, windows-8

While configuring the partitions in installation of ubuntu, it didn't show any of the partitions I have made in 8.1, neither primary or logical drive nor unallocated space of 50GB (made for ubutu).

How to make windows partitions visible in Ubuntu installation & will 50GB space be sufficient for proper functioning of ubuntu?

Comment: did you ever find an answer? I had this problem and I think I screwed up by installing grub to the MBR when the installation suggested I install an mBIOS or something. Also, 50GB should be more than enough to function but might get full of stored data like downloads, movies, music, iso files, etc . . .

Comment: No. I could not find any answer. Finally i ended up through virtualbox. But it is too slow.....

Answer (score 0):

Go to Try Ubuntu (start live distribution), start GParted, make new partition table (i recommend 2GB linux-swap, 40GB linux, 250GB ntfs) and file system set ms-dos (not GPT). Go to install Ubuntu (40GB and bootloader to sda), next windows (250GB) and check it. (sorry for my english)